# How to fetch the current value of table cell in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am using Html table to display the data my aim is to fetch the cell value with I click on the table cell. and set the state based on the value returned from the table cell. I am using jquery to fetch the value from this table it is working but I am unable to update the state.
I am using handle click function to update the state when a user clicks on the table cell but I have no idea how to fetch the table cell value .

below is the code used to display the data.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import $ from "jquery";
import "./../css/index.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link,Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

class Table extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      accounts : [],
      account:'',
      region:'',
   }
   this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    let _this = this;
    let account = "";
    let region = "";
    $("table").on("click", "td", function(e) {
      region = e.delegateTarget.tHead.rows[0].cells[this.cellIndex];
      account = this.parentNode.cells[0];
      account = $(account).text()
      region = $(region).text()
      console.log(region);
      console.log(account);
    });
    const response = await fetch(
      "",
      {
        headers: {
          "x-api-key": ""
        }
      }
    );

    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ accounts:data});
    $(".main-table").clone(true).appendTo('#table-scroll').addClass('clone');

  };
  handleClick(){
    let account = 'zahid';
    let region = 'hussain'
    this.setState(prevState => {
      prevState.account = '';
      prevState.region = '';
      return {
        count: prevState.count * 2,
        account: prevState.account + account,
        region: prevState.region + region
      }
    })
  }
  renderTableData() {
    return this.state.accounts.map((account, index) => {
      const {
        environment,
        account_number,
        bu,
        account_alias,
        resource_name
      } = account; //destructuring
      const regions = account.regions;
      return (
        <tr key={index}>
          <td className="fixed-side">{account_number}</td>
          <td className="fixed-side">{account_alias}</td>
          <td className="fixed-side">{environment}</td>
          <td className="fixed-side">{bu}</td>
          <td>
            <Link to={{
              pathname:"/securityGroups",
              state: { account:'057346956084',region:'us-east-1'}}}>
              {regions["us-east-1"]}
            </Link>
            </td>
          <td>{regions["us-east-2"]}</td>
          <td>{regions["us-west-1"]}</td>
          <td>{regions["us-west-2"]}</td>
          <td>{regions["us-gov-west-1"]}</td>
          <td>{regions["us-gov-east-1"]}</td>
          <td>{regions["sa-east-1"]}</td>
          <td>{regions["me-south-1"]}</td>
          <td onClick={this.handleClick}>{regions["eu-north-1"]}</td>
          <td>{regions["eu-west-3"]}</td>
          <td>{regions["eu-west-2"]}</td>
          <td>{regions["eu-west-1"]}</td>
          <td>{regions["eu-central-1"]}</td>
          <td>{regions["cn-northwest-1"]}</td>
          <td>{regions["cn-north-1"]}</td>
          <td>{regions["ca-central-1"]}</td>
          <td>{regions["ap-northeast-1"]}</td>
          <td>{regions["ap-southeast-2"]}</td>
          <td>{regions["ap-southeast-1"]}</td>
          <td>{regions["ap-northeast-2"]}</td>
          <td>{regions["ap-northeast-3"]}</td>
          <td>{regions["ap-south-1"]}</td>
          <td>{regions["ap-east-1"]}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.count);
    console.log(this.state.account);
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div id="table-scroll" className="table-scroll">
          <div className="table-fixed-right table-wrap">
            <table className="main-table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th className="fixed-side" scope="col">Account Number</th>
                  <th className="fixed-side" scope="col">Account Alias</th>
                  <th className="fixed-side" scope="col">Environment</th>
                  <th  className="fixed-side" scope="col">BU</th>
                  <th scope="col">us-gov-west-1</th>
                  <th scope="col">us-gov-east-1</th>
                  <th scope="col">sa-east-1</th>
                  <th scope="col">me-south-1</th>
                  <th scope="col">eu-north-1 </th>
                  <th scope="col">eu-west-3</th>
                  <th scope="col">eu-west-2</th>
                  <th scope="col">eu-west-1</th>
                  <th scope="col"> eu-central-1</th>
                  <th scope="col">cn-northwest-1</th>
                  <th scope="col"> cn-north-1</th>
                  <th scope="col">ca-central-1</th>
                  <th scope="col">ap-northeast-1</th>
                  <th scope="col"> ap-southeast-2</th>
                  <th scope="col">ap-southeast-1</th>
                  <th scope="col">ap-northeast-2</th>
                  <th scope="col">ap-northeast-3</th>
                  <th scope="col">ap-south-1</th>
                  <th scope="col">ap-east-1</th>
                  <th scope="col">us-west-2</th>
                  <th scope="col">us-west-1</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.renderTableData()}
            {/* <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.account}</button> */}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Table;
```

The below image is my output [![enter image description here][1]][1]

could anyone please tell me how I can achieve this.

Please see the below image I have to get the values of the red box[![enter image description here][2]][2] have specified

Answer (score 4):

You really don't need jQuery if you're using react.  React makes it really easy and quick to manipulate the dom.  Using jQuery alongside react is an antipattern.

That being said, in your example, you'll want to use `onClick` and if you know the content of the cells, (in this case what you're displaying in the UI), you can just pass that value to the handler.

Use `onClick` on the cells:

```
 // here we pass handleCellClick the value of `regions["us-east-2"])`
<td onClick={() => handleCellClick(regions["us-east-2"])}>
    {regions["us-east-2"]}
</td>
```

Define the click handler in your component something like this.  `content` will be whatever you passed.

```
handleCellClick(content) {
  //... do stuff

}
```

To get the text from your table headers:

```
<th scope="col" onClick={this.handleHeaderClick}>                    
    us-gov-west-1
</th>
```

And define `handleHeaderClick` like:

```
handleHeaderClick(event) {
    const value = event.target.textContent;
    console.log(value);
}
```

If you only need to pass the text content of anything on the table clicked, whether cells or table headers, you can use the same pattern.  If that is the case, you could use a single function bound in the same way for every element.  If you need to pass additional arguments along with getting the `textContent` it would look like this:

```
<td
   onClick={event => this.handleClickWithAdditionalArgs(event, "Whatever other value I want to pass")}>
        {regions["me-south-1"]}
</td>
```

And the function defined as:

```
handleClickWithAdditionalArgs(event, otherArg) {
    const value = event.target.textContent;
    console.log(value); // the text in the element clicked
    console.log(otherArg); // whatever else you pass 
  }
```

Again, you mentioned needing to send the "account" on click.  I do not know what that is based on your code provided.  If you clarify what you mean by that, I can show you.  You've asked to get the content of cells when clicked, I've displayed how to do that multiple ways now.  1) by passing whatever value you want explicitly into your function and 2) by parsing the dom to get the `textContent`.

Comment: could you please give me an example

Comment: This is an example.  Is there a specific part of it that is not making sense?

Comment: actually I also have to fetch the account no with respect to that cell. i am not getting how to achieve this

Comment: You can pass in any value to that function.  If you need the `account_number`, it would look like: `onClick={() => handleCellClick(account_number)}`.  What do you mean by account?  `account_alias`? `account_number`?  Please be specific as to what you are looking for.

Comment: I have added one more image could you please take a look and guide me

Comment: My examples should work for you or guide you to what you are looking for.  Is there part of it that you are not understanding?  If you understand my examples, I believe you will be able to accomplish what you are looking for.